# Can not get last report for iTunes connect

Tags: java, app-store-connect

We are using the apple Autoingestion class file to fetch stats about our downloads from iTunes connect.

In the last 3 days though the last report has been always behind and we are not able to get the report from the day before, doing this for example gives:

```
java -classpath /Users/andrea/depop/depop-backend/garage/libs Autoingestion autoingestion.properties 85509988 Sales Daily Summary 20140811
```

"reports are available only for past 30 days, please enter a date within past 30 days."

But the worrying thing is that from this documentation:

http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

Date is optional, and not passed in it should give the LAST report.
Well omitting the date we still get exactly the same error, so it's the last report that just fails all the time..

Answer (score 0):

The reports have been abnormally late the past few days and iTunes Connect's Sales and Trends page seems to be not working at all for long periods. I'd say your issue is related to whatever is happening to Apple.